# How do I write two Python classes, Square and NGon, as follows?

Tags: python, class

classes Square and NGon are as follows:

-NGon objects are initialized with several comma-separated floats, representing the side lengths of a closed polygon. For instance, NGon(1.0, 1.0, 1.414) would initialize a triangle, NGon(2.0, 3,0, 2.0, 3.0) could describe a rectangle. Note that the number of arguments can vary. If fewer than 3 arguments are provided, your code must raise an error message.

-NGon provides a perimeter() method, which returns the sum of the side lengths of the object. For instance, NGon(2.0,3.0,5.0).perimeter() must return 10.0.

-NGon objects can be converted to a string with str(). The conversion must return a string of the form 'I am a(n) x-gon.'  Here x is the appropriate number of sides.

-The Square class inherits the perimeter() method from the  NGon class.

-Square objects are initialized with a single argument -- the side length, e.g., Square(5.0) initializes a square with side length 5.0.

-When square objects are converted to a string, they return a string of the form 'I am a square with area y.' Here y is the area of the square.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Is `perimeter` the *only* method that `NGon` will expose? If there were a method to, for example, increase the length of exactly one side, then `Square` should not be a subclass of `NGon` at all.

Comment: I can figure out NGon just fine, but I'm not sure what my fourth bullet means by "inherits", just that it has the same feature? Or is Square some sort of piece of NGon? I'm new to coding.